# Джанго, время жизни сессии

Tags: python, django, http, cookie

Нужна помощь, когда я делаю request.META, там есть HTTP_COOKIE с ключом csrftoken, аот хотел узнать в какое время оно обновиться, будет новые значения? и как сделать так что бы через 5 часов менялся ключ, но я сессии не использую

Comment: csrftoken меняется при каждом запросе и не имеет отношения к сессии.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev не меняется уже 6 часов, больше 100 запросов цже сделал

Comment: А должен. Вся суть [CSRF](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/) в этом.